# Organization Tree chart CSS fix-width when stretched

Tags: html, css

I build a tree organization (parent & child) chart based on this [Example](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree), but when i minimize my browser the tree structure will get messy, i want the position to be fixed so i can just scroll it to the right if it contain another child because i have to set the width of tree class to 15000px so it doesn't get messy

here's the code:

```css
 html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    html {
        display: table;
        margin: auto;
    }

    body {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    /*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

    .tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
    }
    .tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    /*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without
    any siblings*/
    .tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
    }

    /*Remove space from the top of single children*/
    .tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

    /*Remove left connector from first child and
    right connector from last child*/
    .tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
    }
    /*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
    .tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    }
    .tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    }

    /*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
    .tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
    }

    .tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }


    /*Time for some hover effects*/
    /*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
    .tree li a:hover {
    background: rgba(19, 79, 82, 0.4); color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
    }
```

```html
<div class="tree" style="max-width:14444px;display: inline-block;">
    <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
          {{-- There is at least 200 childs, in my example i only include 1 child --}}
          <li> 
            <a href="#">Child</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to add `white-space:nowrap` to the `ul`, replace `float:left` by `display:inline-block` to the `li`.

```
.tree ul {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.tree li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And you can remove the `max-width` from the `.tree`.

Here you can see the example: http://codepen.io/joruus/pen/GjXQVj